# How does Doctrine2 One-To-Many fetch=EAGER work?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2.8 / Doctrine ORM 2.5.2.

I have 2 entities, `Gallery` OneToMany `File`

```
class Gallery
{
    /**
     * @var File[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="gallery", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $files;
}
```

I see 2 things in the documentation.

First, now the OneToMany relationship does have the `fetch=EAGER` option ([specified here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetomany)). It was not there in previous versions.

Second, the manual setting for this fetch method per query seems not available for OneToMany but I don't know if [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) is up-to-date as it states:

> Changing the fetch mode during a query is only possible for one-to-one
>   and many-to-one relations.

I have anyway tried both, here is my query:

```
public function findWithEager()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $query->setFetchMode("CommonBundle\\Entity\\Gallery", "files", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

But when I do:

```
foreach ($galleryRepository->findWithEager() as $gallery) {
    foreach ($gallery->getFiles() as $file) {
        $file->getId();
    }
}
```

Then I got 1+n queries. The first is `SELECT * FROM Gallery` and the n following ones are `SELECT * FROM File WHERE id = :galleryId`

I would like Doctrine to do 1+1 queries, the second one being `SELECT * FROM File WHERE id IN (:galleryListIds)`

Did I miss something? Is this behavior implemented in Doctrine?

The [latest doctrine changelog](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html#improve-efficiency-of-one-to-many-eager) states:

> When marking a one-to-many association with fetch="EAGER" it will now
>   execute one query less than before and work correctly in combination
>   with indexBy.

It is not clear at all what is the expected behavior.

Any insight is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Which version of Doctrine are you using?  Should be 2.5.

Comment: I'm using doctrine orm v2.5.2.

Comment: If you're using the queryBuilder to retrieve your objects, you should use a leftJoin, and not the fetch strategy :/
 
Did you also try with a plain ->findAll() and a loop on your files?

Answer (score 13):

After much searching and some testing (using `Doctrine ORM 2.5.6` on `PHP 5.6`) I have some results.

At this time it is not possible to get your `Gallery` entities with one query and all related `File` entities with a second query.

## You have two options

**Get Gallery and File entities in one query using `Left Join`.**

- This is what the `->find*` methods do when you set `fetch="EAGER"` on your annotation.
- You can do this manually with DQL: `SELECT g, f FROM Gallery g LEFT JOIN g.files f`

As [noted in the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql), you cannot call `->setFetchMode('Gallery', 'files', ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER)` on a DQL query to achieve the same result

> ... For one-to-many relations, changing the fetch mode to eager will cause to execute one query for every root entity loaded. This gives no improvement over the lazy fetch mode which will also initialize the associations on a one-by-one basis once they are accessed.

This will result in n additional queries being run immediately after your first query to fetch your Gallery entities.

**Get Gallery entities with one query and lazy-load the File entities.**

- This is Doctrine's default behaviour (`fetch="LAZY"`) and will result in 1 query plus an additional query for each set of `Gallery#$files` you access (1+n queries if you access them all).

## Possible Future Option

There is a [PR to add an `EAGER_BATCHED` fetch option](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1569) which would do exactly what you want (fetch `Gallery` entities with one query then fetch all `File` entities with a second query) but there doesn't seem to be much happening with it, unfortunately.

## Conclusion

If you're using the `->find*` methods, `fetch="EAGER"` annotations will be respected. Doctrine will do this with a LEFT JOIN. Depending on your data set this could be ok or very expensive.

If you're writing DQL manually or using the query builder you must `LEFT JOIN` one-to-many relations AND remember to add any entities you want fetched to the select clause.

My preference is to write DQL whenever you want a one-to-many relation fetched eagerly because it makes your intention clear.